# How to use Google Cloud Search and Vision API together

Tags: google-cloud-vision

everyone,
I have a completely untypical topic at this point and I hope that I am addressing the right people here.
I'm working on a personal project. I recently became a G Suite customer and would like to map my document and media management via Google Drive. The document management works well so far and with the help of Google Cloud Search I can easily find my documents across platforms.

Since I personally take a lot of pictures, I was wondering if I could use Google products to find a way to classify my pictures automatically. My approach was to use the label detection of the Vision API to store the 5 most likely labels as metadata. By using the metadata, I can then, when I search for example for architecture or animal, find all images that contain one of the following terms in a single search. The concept should of course be extendable to location and text detection.
I have already tried to create an automatism via pages like integromat.com that labels the photos, but unfortunately without success.
Well and now we come to the current situation. Since I realized that an active interaction with the Google Cloud is essential, I am looking for help from an experienced community. I hope that maybe someone here has a good or inspiring idea.

Maybe one more hint before the proposal is made. Google Photos is great and can do something like that, but it doesn't integrate with Google Cloud Search and managing RAW files would be terrible.

Comment: please be specific

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the following approach:

1. Build a web/mobile app to upload photos to Google Drive or Cloud Storage.
2. Use the Google Vision API to fetch metadata from your image before uploading to Drive/Cloud Storage.
3. Use Google [Cloud Search Rest API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest) to index the extracted metadata along with the image URL to Cloud Search.
4. Create a custom Search Interface to search and display your indexed images.

Above steps should be able to point you in the right direction in implementing the solution. Let me know if you need further help with it.

Comment: is this can apply as same to the vision product search API? like for my own image data set with meta data?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question